# Framerate and game loop on mobile

Tags: android, ios, android-ndk, frame-rate, game-loop

I'm searching how to manage game framerate on mobiles devices, here is my problem:

**On a computer with got something like that:**

```
void main()
{
    while(game.isRunning())
    {
        event.handle(eventInfos);
        game.update(dt);
        graphic.render();
    }
}
```

**On a mobile device with got something like that:**

```
void update()
{
    game.update(dt);
}

void render()
{
    game.render(dt);
}

void event()
{
    game.handle(eventInfos);
}
```

When I search on internet, I found something like that everytime:

[-> GameLoop](http://obviam.net/index.php/the-android-game-loop/)

[-> Fix your time step](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/)

I'm using IOS (With GLKViewController) and Android (with the NDK), and I've that rendering method is call from another thread

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I findthe GameLoop link you have posted is very straight forward, he runs a thread which in its turn check for right time to call `update()` in these lines

```
            while (sleepTime < 0 && framesSkipped < MAX_FRAME_SKIPS) {
            // we need to catch up
            // update without rendering
            this.gamePanel.update(); 
            // add frame period to check if in next frame
            sleepTime += FRAME_PERIOD;  
            framesSkipped++;
        }
```